# I've built my app for OSX Lion but when i run it is always on bottom of the screen

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I've built my app for OSX Lion but when i run it is always on bottom of the screen.

What could be the reason ??
thanks!

ps. The current position of the window is restored.. so the window position is restored but the window is always on the back, the assigned layer is wrong, it wasn't on the bottom when it was close.

ps2. Is maybe because the main file of my app is the mainMenu.xib and not document.xib ? I can't change that.

Comment: What does "it is always on bottom of the screen." mean? It's always in the dock? The window is positioned at the bottom?

Comment: Sorry, it is always on the bottom layer. other windows and other apps are over it. It is not invisible unless I move other apps windows, or click on it.

Comment: Peculiar, it sounds like you have unintentionally changed the *level* of your window. A normal window should have a level of `NSNormalWindowLevel`. You can obtain a window's level with `[myWindow level]`, try `NSLog`ing that and see what you get.

Do you have any calls to `setLevel:`? If so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CRD I've setted [[self window] setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel]; but it doesn't work... print NSLog(@"%i", [myWindow level]) gives 0 which is the NSNormalWindowLevel

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I launch my app in OSX Lion, it always runs on the bottom layer, behind other apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683097/when-i-launch-my-app-in-osx-lion-it-always-runs-on-the-bottom-layer-behind-oth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
//disable Lion resume
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"ApplePersistenceIgnoreState"] == nil)
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ApplePersistenceIgnoreState"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about your application window, its position is taken either from your XIB/NIB file (if that's what you use) or you specify it in the code as the frame for the window. In a XIB/NIB you can specify a name in the "Autosave" field (under Window attributes) which will cause your app to remember the last window size and position across launches so it doesn't always start at the place you defined in the XIB/NIB.

EDIT: since you mean bottom *layer*, try calling `[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]`, e.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Comment: I can't solve this issue. My app window is always on the bottom, behind all other windows. The only way to make it appear is to click on the dock icon, or to remove other windows. The current position is restored through.. so it should work...