# When I launch my app in OSX Lion, it always runs on the bottom layer, behind other apps

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

When I launch my app in OSX Lion, it always runs on the bottom layer, behind other apps.

I suspect the issue is related to the new feature in Lion about restoring the last configuration of the main window. Indeed, if I delete the app folder from the Library/Saved Application State folder, and I run again my app, the main window is displayed on top.

Also, if I click on the dock bar, the apps come in front, but it never starts in front of other apps.

I've tried several things such as:

> - clean the AutoSave field in the xib file
> - setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel (if I use NSSubmenuWindowLevel, it stays always in front even when it looses focus)
> - [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]

but none had worked.

I don't know if this matters, but my base xib file in the app preferences is "mainMenu.xib" and not "document.xib". COuld be that the mainWindow is considered the main application window and therefore not shown on top ?

In any case I think there is something wrong in the code, because the app should show up on top of the window when it is launched by default.

Thanks

Comment: in the attributes inspector for the window, try unchecking "Restorable". for a programmatic solution, you could try `– orderFrontRegardless`.

Comment: I've tried orderFrontRegardless but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by disabling the Resume with

```
//disable Lion resume
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"ApplePersistenceIgnoreState"] == nil)
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ApplePersistenceIgnoreState"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that happen for some reason as well, though it only seems to happen when running under the debugger.

Try calling `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

Comment: This will make your application **steal the focus** if the user is doing something else while waiting for your application to launch. Don't do that, at least not in a release version. (Even if your application is ordinarily snappy, it may be slowed by e.g. heavy memory paging, or being loaded from a network filesystem.)

Comment: @Kevin Reid Ok I won't do it, but how to solve it ? It always appears on the back of other apps...